# Qt ActiveX Word изменение формата таблицы

Tags: c++, qt, ms-word, activex

Столкнулся с необходимостью работы с Word в Qt. Необходимо задать формат ширины каждого столбца, а так же объединить некоторые ячейки. По экселю - ясно. Как сделать в ворде не понятно.

```
QAxObject *m_word = new QAxObject("Word.Application");
QAxObject* docs = m_word->querySubObject( "Documents" );

QVariant filename("D:\\...\\word\\...\\doc.doc");
QVariant confirmconversions(false);
QVariant readonly(false);
QVariant addtorecentfiles(false);
QVariant passworddocument("");
QVariant passwordtemplate("");
QVariant revert(false);

QAxObject* doc = docs->querySubObject("Open(const QVariant&, const QVariant&, "
                                      "const QVariant&, const QVariant&, const QVariant&, const QVariant&,"
                                      "const QVariant&)", filename, confirmconversions, readonly,
                                      addtorecentfiles, passworddocument, passwordtemplate, revert);

QAxObject *ActiveDocument = m_word->querySubObject("ActiveDocument()");
QAxObject *Range = ActiveDocument->querySubObject("Range()");
QAxObject *font = Range->querySubObject("Font");
Range->dynamicCall("InsertAfter(Text)", "текст");
Range->setProperty("Alignment", 2);
font->setProperty("Alignment", 2);
font->setProperty("Name", "Times New Roman");
font->setProperty("Size", 14);
font->setProperty("Bold", 2);

QAxObject* selection = m_word->querySubObject("Selection") ;
QAxObject* Tables = selection->querySubObject("Tables()");
QAxObject* NewTable = Tables->querySubObject("Add(const QVariant&, const QVariant&, const QVariant&, "
                                             "const QVariant& DefaultTableBehavior, const QVariant& AutoFitBehavior)", ActiveDocument->dynamicCall("Range()"), 3, 4, 1, 1);

QAxObject* cell = NewTable->querySubObject("Cell(Row, Column)" , QVariant(1), QVariant(1)) ;
QAxObject* celR = cell->querySubObject("Range()") ;
celR->dynamicCall("InsertAfter(Text)", "Это ячейка 1:1,kz,kz,zk,zk,zk,zk.kzhtrhrhrthtrhrt");

cell = NewTable->querySubObject("Cell(Row, Column)" , 1, 2) ;
celR = cell->querySubObject("Range()") ;
celR->dynamicCall("InsertAfter(Text)", "Это ячейка 1:2");
cell = NewTable->querySubObject("Cell(Row, Column)" , 1, 3) ;
celR = cell->querySubObject("Range()") ;
celR->dynamicCall("InsertAfter(Text)", "Это ячейка 1:3");
cell = NewTable->querySubObject("Cell(Row, Column)" , 1, 4) ;
celR = cell->querySubObject("Range()") ;
celR->dynamicCall("InsertAfter(Text)", "Это ячейка 1:4");
cell = NewTable->querySubObject("Cell(Row, Column)" , 2, 1) ;
celR = cell->querySubObject("Range()") ;
celR->dynamicCall("InsertAfter(Text)", "Это ячейка 2:1");
cell = NewTable->querySubObject("Cell(Row, Column)" , 2, 2) ;
celR = cell->querySubObject("Range()") ;
celR->dynamicCall("InsertAfter(Text)", "Это ячейка 2:2");
cell = NewTable->querySubObject("Cell(Row, Column)" , 3, 1) ;
celR = cell->querySubObject("Range()") ;
celR->dynamicCall("InsertAfter(Text)", "Это ячейка 3:1");

delete celR;
delete cell;
delete NewTable;
delete Tables;
delete selection;
delete font;
delete Range;

m_word->querySubObject("ActiveDocument")->dynamicCall("Close()");
m_word->dynamicCall("SetDisplayAlerts(bool)", false);
m_word->dynamicCall("Quit()");

delete ActiveDocument;
delete doc;
delete docs;
delete m_word;
```

Answer (score 0):

Если ширину конки поменять то так :

```
   QAxObject *razmer = celR->querySubObject("Columns()");
    razmer->setProperty("Width",300);// устанавливаю её размер
```

Answer (score -2):

Самый простой способ увеличить ширину:

```
cell->setProperty("Width", "100");
```